# VBA check inputbox value origin

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I have a piece of code that asks the user to input text to write on my sheet, but, I want to do separate things when the user types plain text (simply typing the desired text) or the user references a sheet cell to get its value from as a input.

What can I do?

```
Dim mensagem As Variant
mensagem = Application.InputBox("Qual o motivo da pendência?", "O protocolo geral precisa saber...")
If Not (mensagem = False Or mensagem = vbNullString) Then
    If xxxx Then '(1) reference cell
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Columns(17).Value = mensagem
        'do stuff
    ElseIf yyyyyy Then '(2) plain text
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Columns(17).Value = mensagem
        ' do different stuff
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

[image]_______[image]

Comment: Using that approach, there's no way to tell if the user selected a cell or entered a value directly.  I deleted my previous answer, since I'd assumed without checking that  `mensagem` would be (eg) "=$D$1" and not the value of the selected cell...